# How is this variable in the constructor initialized in C#?

Tags: c#

I am new to C#, porting some code over to TypeScript from C#. In the C# code, it says this:

```
public TilingConfig( int p, int q, int maxTiles ) : this() 
    {
        SetupConfig( p, q, maxTiles );
    }

    public TilingConfig( int p, int q ) : this()
    {
        if( Geometry2D.GetGeometry( p, q ) != Geometry.Spherical )
            throw new System.ArgumentException();

        SetupConfig( p, q, PlatonicSolids.NumFacets( p, q ) );
    }

    private void SetupConfig( int p, int q, int maxTiles )
    {
        P = p;
        Q = q;
        m.Unity();
        MaxTiles = maxTiles;
        Shrink = 1.0;
    }

    public int P { get; set; }
    public int Q { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// The induced geometry.
    /// </summary>
    public Geometry Geometry { get { return Geometry2D.GetGeometry( this.P, this.Q ); } }

    /// <summary>
    /// A Mobius transformation to apply while creating the tiling.
    /// </summary>
    public Mobius M { get { return m; } set { m = value; } }
    private Mobius m;

    /// <summary>
    /// The max number of tiles to include in the tiling.
    /// </summary>
    public int MaxTiles { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// A shrinkage to apply to the drawn portion of a tile.
    /// Default is 1.0 (no shrinkage).
    /// </summary>
    public double Shrink { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Returns a Mobius transform that can be used to create a dual {q,p} tiling.
    /// This Mobius transform will center the tiling on a vertex.
    /// </summary>
    public Mobius VertexCenteredMobius()
    {
        return VertexCenteredMobius( this.P, this.Q );
    }

    public static Mobius VertexCenteredMobius( int p, int q )
    {
        double angle = Math.PI / q;
        if( Utils.Even( q ) )
            angle *= 2;
        Vector3D offset = new Vector3D( -1 * Geometry2D.GetNormalizedCircumRadius( p, q ), 0, 0 );
        offset.RotateXY( angle );
        Mobius m = new Mobius();
        m.Isometry( Geometry2D.GetGeometry( p, q ), angle, offset.ToComplex() );
        return m;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// This Mobius transform will center the tiling on an edge.
    /// </summary>
    public Mobius EdgeMobius()
    {
        Geometry g = Geometry2D.GetGeometry( this.P, this.Q );

        Polygon poly = new Polygon();
        poly.CreateRegular( this.P, this.Q );
        Segment seg = poly.Segments[0];
        Vector3D offset = seg.Midpoint;

        double angle = Math.PI / this.P;
        offset.RotateXY( -angle );

        Mobius m = new Mobius();
        m.Isometry( g, -angle, -offset );
        return m;
    }
}
```

Specifically the line in `SetupConfig`, which says:

```
m.Unity();
```

Where is that `m` instantiated? Is it a default of some sort? If so, where is the default specified for `Mobius` type? [Here](https://github.com/roice3/Honeycombs/blob/bdc60f6057920d338f4bb59c87041350fefe08cf/code/R3/R3.Core/Geometry/Tiling.cs#L32) is the full source code.

Comment: `Mobius` is a `struct` which is value type. It does not require initialization with `new` unless you want to call a custom constructor. `Mobius m` would be just similar to `int i`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this [source code](https://github.com/roice3/Honeycombs/blob/bdc60f6057920d338f4bb59c87041350fefe08cf/code/R3/R3.Core/Math/Mobius.cs) you can check that the Mobius is a struct.
Struct can be define without constructor.
[Docs.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/builtin-types/struct)